# "File not found" error when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html

This is an application for my website and I don't quite understand what is wrong with it. I have had colleagues looking at it and we can't quite figure out where the error is.

This is supposed to be a game of guess the number, where a random number is generated and the user is supposed to guess it; depending on how close you are to the answer, the colour should change.  But instead it pops up a file not found error when the button is clicked.

```js
const int = document.getElementById("Guess");
const LowOrHigh = document.querySelector("LowOrHigh");
const TimesGuessed = document.querySelector("TimesGuessed");
const WinOrLose = document.querySelector("WinOrLose");
let numberOfGuesses = 0;
const Color = document.querySelector("#Guess");
const RandomNumber = Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1;
const win = "false";

const THEGODDAMBUTTON = document.getElementById("TreasureSubmitButton").addEventListener("click", Hey);

function Hey(int) {
  let Guess = parseInt(int.valueOf);

  if (RandomNumber === Guess) {
    Color.style.backgroundColor = "#007F00";
    Color.style.color = "#ffffff";
    TimesGuessed.innerHTML('You have guessed ${numberOfGuesses} times');
    win = "correct";
  } else if (Guess > RandomNumber - 10 && Guess < RandomNumber || Guess < RandomNumber + 10 && Guess > RandomNumber) {
    Color.style.backgroundColor = "#990000";
    Color.style.color = "#ffffff";
    numberOfGuesses++;
    if (Guess > RandomNumber) {
      LowOrHigh.innerHTML("Too high!");
    } else if (Guess < RandomNumber) {
      LowOrHigh.innerHTML("Too small!");
    }
    TimesGuessed.innerHTML('You have guessed ${numberOfGuesses} times');
    WinOrLose.innerHTML("Good guess, try again!");
  } else if (Guess > RandomNumber - 30 && Guess < RandomNumber || Guess < RandomNumber + 30 && Guess > RandomNumber) {
    Color.style.backgroundColor = "#000099";
    Color.style.color = "#ffffff";
    numberOfGuesses++;
    if (Guess > RandomNumber) {
      LowOrHigh.innerHTML("Too high!");
    } else if (Guess < RandomNumber) {
      LowOrHigh.innerHTML("Too small!");
    }
    TimesGuessed.innerHTML('You have guessed ${numberOfGuesses} times');
    WinOrLose.innerHTML("Good guess, try again!");
  } else {
    Color.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    Color.style.color = "#000000";
    numberOfGuesses++;
    if (Guess > RandomNumber) {
      LowOrHigh.innerHTML("Too high!");
    } else if (Guess < RandomNumber) {
      LowOrHigh.innerHTML("Too small!");
    }
    TimesGuessed.innerHTML('You have guessed ${numberOfGuesses} times');
    WinOrLose.innerHTML("Good guess, try again!");
  }
}
console.log(RandomNumber);
```

```html
<div id="TreasureHunt">
  <form action=submit method="post">
    <fieldset id="guessFieldset">
      <legend><strong>Please enter a number between 1 and 100</strong></legend>
      <p>
        <label for="Number:">Number:</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="Guess" name="Guess">
      </p>
      <button type="submit" id="TreasureSubmitButton">Guess!</button>
      <button type="submit" id="TreasureRestartButton">New game</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="hintFieldset">
      <legend><strong>Hint</strong></legend>
      <p id="LowOrHigh"></p>
      <p id="TimesGuessed"></p>
      <p id="WinOrLose"></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <p>In this game, your job is to guess the a number between 1 and 100! During the game, in the hint area, there will be displayed a color, if you are too high or too low and how many guesses you've had. Once you get the right number the hint area will shine
    in green and you can restart the game by clickin new game. Try to guess wi the least guesses possible!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things going on here. First, the file not found is happening because it is looking for a file called "submit" since you have:
`<form action=submit method="post">`. You don't need this property, nor do you need the `method="post"` because you're not sending your form data anywhere.

The second thing happening is that you're not passing your Hey() function an int. Since you're not using post, the form data isn't going anywhere. When you call Hey() you need to pass in `document.getElementById('Guess').value` since that's where you have it OR do something like this:

```
// no args
function Hey() {
  let Guess = document.getElementById('Guess').value;
```

Hope that helps!